# Perl - Identify all elements in a hash that have the highest value

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I wrote some Perl code that searches for the highest key-value pair in a hash in which the keys are text and the values are numbers:

```
my $o_val = 0;    # FOR TRACKING HIGHEST VALUE ENCOUNTERED IN THE LOOP
my $o_key;        # FOR TRACKING CORRESPONDING KEY TO THE HIGHEST VALUE
while ( my ($key, $val) = each(%NG) ) {
        if ( $val > $o_val ) {
                $o_val = $val;
                $o_key = $key;
        }
}
print "$okey\n";
```

The problem is that it does nothing to account for the possibility of a tie for highest value. **How can I capture all the key-value pairs that tied for highest value if my measuring variable can potentially change with each iteration of the loop?**

I have the idea that I could write another while loop to run through the same hash after $o_val had been established as the highest value then push each key paired to $o_val into another array, something like:

```
my @highest;     # ARRAY OF HIGHEST-VALUE KEYS
while ( my ($key, $val) = each(%NG) ) {
    if ( $val == $o_val ) { push(@highest, $key); }
}
```

but this seems kinda inefficient. I'm hoping there are some Perl commands I'm not aware of that will let me identify the highest value in the hash without looping through it so I can just use the second piece of code in my question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an array to keep the keys for highest value,

```
if ( $val > $o_val ) {
  $o_val  = $val;
  @o_keys = $key;
}
elsif ($val == $o_val) {
  push(@o_keys, $key);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %h = map { $_ => int(rand 10)} 'a' .. 'z';

# see what we've got
my @k = sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h;
print "$_ => $h{$_}\n" for @k;

# initialize $max with a value from %h
my ($max) = values %h;
# keys with highest values
my @argmax;

while (my ($k, $v) = each %h) {
    next if $v < $max;
    if ($v > $max) {
        $max = $v;
        @argmax = ($k);
    }
    else {
        push @argmax, $k
    }
}

print "@argmax\n";
print "@h{ @argmax }\n";
```

Of course, if you don't care much about memory, or if you are golfing, or japhing, you could write something like:

```
my %v;
push @{ $v{$h{$_}} }, $_ for keys %h;
my ($max) = sort { $b <=> $a } keys %v;
print "@{ $v{$max} } => $max\n"
```

Comment: I had no idea what golfing or japhing were until I read your answer. You've opened up a whole new world for me to explore.